# How can we import shapes (dash) for SHACL validation in Apache Jena?

Tags: owl, jena, shacl

How can we import shapes for SHACL validation in Apache Jena?

I am trying to use the DASH (https://datashapes.org/dash.html) shapes vocabulary to validate an ontology in Jena. The code is quite simple:

```java
        String SHAPES = """
                @prefix : <https://example.com/> .
                @prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
                @prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
                @prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
                @prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
                @prefix dash: <http://datashapes.org/dash#> .
                                
                <https://example.com/> a owl:Ontology ;
                  owl:imports <http://datashapes.org/dash> .
                                
                :person a sh:NodeShape ; a rdfs:Class ;
                  dash:closedByTypes true ;
                  sh:ignoredProperties (
                    rdf:type
                  ) ;
                  sh:property [
                    sh:path :name ;
                  ]
                .
                """;

        String DATA = """
                @prefix : <https://example.com/> .
                @prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
                :person-1 a :person ;
                  :name "John"^^xsd:string ;
                .  
                """;

RDFParser shapesTurtleParser = RDFParser.source(new ByteArrayInputStream(SHAPES.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
       .forceLang(Lang.TTL)
       .build();

Graph shapesGraph = shapesTurtleParser.toGraph();

// If I don't put this line, the validation pass. 
shapesGraph = Imports.withImports(shapesGraph);

RDFParser dataTurtleParser = RDFParser.source(new ByteArrayInputStream(DATA.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
       .forceLang(Lang.TTL)
       .build();

Graph dataGraph = dataTurtleParser.toGraph();

ValidationReport report = ShaclValidator.get().validate(shapesGraph, dataGraph);
RDFDataMgr.write(System.out, report.getModel(), Lang.TTL);
```

Here is the result from the validation:

```
@prefix :     <https://example.com/> .
@prefix dash: <http://datashapes.org/dash#> .
@prefix owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix sh:   <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
@prefix tosh: <http://topbraid.org/tosh#> .
@prefix xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

[ rdf:type     sh:ValidationReport;
  sh:conforms  false;
  sh:result    [ rdf:type                      sh:ValidationResult;
                 sh:focusNode                  :person-1;
                 sh:resultMessage              "Property <https://example.com/name> is not among those permitted for any of the types";
                 sh:resultPath                 :name;
                 sh:resultSeverity             sh:Violation;
                 sh:sourceConstraintComponent  dash:ClosedByTypesConstraintComponent;
                 sh:sourceShape                :person;
                 sh:value                      "John"
               ]
] .
```

I get un unexpected validation error: `sh:ClosedConstraintComponent` which I should not have since the property (:name) is declared in the shape itself.

What do I miss or do incorrectly in my SHACL validation?

Comment: Could you produce a smaller, self-contained example please? The setup is quite complicated; I seem to get 7 violations. Notes (1) Jena does not load imports from the classpath (2) the versions of dash, tosh and shacl.ttl that TopQuadrant SHACL uses are not the same as the versions on the web.

Comment: dash/tosh overwrites some standard definitions with forms specific to the TopQuadrant engine. With an extracted `dash:ListShape`, and loading just that extension, and it seems to work, both on the given data (which isn't a list) and with a list at `:name`.

Comment: I modified the example to focus on the `owl:imports` problem. I discovered other problems that I will cover somewhere else. (1) In my code, I removed the files from the classpath, they were not necessary as the TopBraid library includes them. But, in Apache Jena I expect to be able to just declare the `imports` in the source and tell Jena to load them with `withImports` method. (Maybe even this should be done automatically...).

Comment: You can have what control you like with `Shapes shapes = Shapes.parse(URI/file, withImports=true)` then `ShaclValidator.get().validate(Shapes shapes, Graph data)`.

Comment: A Jena `Shapes` is the parsed SHACL shapes. Jena builds the SHACL datastructure once, then validation can be called repeatedly. The TopBraid libraries included in the TopQuadrant code are TopBraid specific. They don't properly parse without TopBraid java code (there are ill-formed SPARQL queries). It also modifies both how Jena SHACL works by reloading custom definitions that are in the standard and also how SPARQL function calls happen.

Comment: If I use only Apache Jena, with the `Shapes shapes = Shapes.parse(URI/file, withImports=true) then ShaclValidator.get().validate(Shapes shapes, Graph data)` code, and using only the dash.ttl from the standard, I still get the same errors (as described in the question). When you say "With an extracted dash:ListShape, and loading just that extension" can you share that code somewhere? The way I extract, it does not validate the list. Also, I can go around using DASH (and the imports problem) since I am generating dynamically my SHACL shapes, although I would prefer not.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/afs/909977164a6baab961d704b5b978014f - include or parse the file into the shapes. Avoid importing web dash at all - it causes problems because it redefines elements in the standard such as sh:ClosedConstraintComponent.